# Custom PDF form to edit multiple fields in document

Tags: pdf, customization

I understand how to create an editable PDF form, but wonder if it is possible to create a document with a form at the beginning that updates multiple fields throughout the document using tags to fill using the information from the inital form.

For example, a textbook for students with a form on page 1 which contains fields for:

Teacher: Mr. Smith [user editable]

Boy 1: Tom [user editable]

Boy 2: David [user editable]

Girl 1: Susan [user editable]

Girl 2: Claire [user editable]

And then on subsequent pages something like:

---

@Teacher@: Hello, @Boy 1@. How are you today?

@Boy 1@: I'm good, thanks!

->

Mr. Smith: Hello, Tom. How are you today?

Tom: I'm good, thanks!

---

@Boy 2@: Hi, @Girl 1@, do you want to go to the cinema on Saturday?

@Girl 1@: That sounds fun, let's invite @Girl 2@ and @Boy 1@!

->

David: Hi, Susan, do you want to go to the cinema on Saturday?

Susan: That sounds fun, let's invite Claire and Tom!

---

Ideally the forms would be pre-filled with default names, like the example above, and the user would be able to edit the names to match those in the class.

Is this possible in the scope of a PDF file, or would it be necessary to use some kind of web application that adds the information before exporting to PDF?

Comment: Only in a dynamic XFA form where content reflow. Because they are not well supported I would think the web application route would be best

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, just took a look at XFA, interesting possibilities but I think you’re right and support would be an issue.